# how to iterate .each loop one recursion less

Tags: jquery

I have an .each loop in jQuery.

I want to iterate the loop one time less. i.e if 4 elements are found matching, than the loop should iterate only 3 times.

PS: Not using var i and i++ etc. But actually looping 1 less.

Comment: So you don't want to iterate over the last element of the list of matching items?

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`.slice( <start>, <end> )`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method (negative `end` = offset relative to the end):

```
$(some_object).slice(0, -1).each( ... );
```